# How to monitor a video stream problems

Tags: video, stream, monitoring, analysis, ffprobe

I have a dvb-s and dvb-t card on my server and installed mumudvb.
How to monitor a video streamed from mumudvb or directly from dvb.
problems like blank screen, noisy pictures, sound problems.
mumudvb can report snr, signal strength and... from satellite.
but I need to know is it possible to detect video problems?
When the operator sees a problem on the screen I need to detect the signal power has problem or TV broadcaster(encoders and ...) works correctly or not.

Thank you.